# I am getting an error in ecllipse that a class is missing from Jar and the class is not the JAR , what can be done in this case?

Tags: java, eclipse

[image]

I am trying to read data from excel in eclipse for my project

Comment: First, it might be better to add the text of the exception into this question. Pictures that are links aren't generally helpful and don't get as many views. Second, you will need to find the jar that has that class and download it. You probably need a different version of the jar

Comment: Welcome to SO. First of all, please take a minute to read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Stackoverflow guide. Also, when you post your question on SO, prefer a copy/paste of stacktrace and code sample instead of using an image.

Comment: thanks for suggestion will keep in mind for next time.

Comment: Fixed your image. Someone else will need to transcribe it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Snacktrace](http://snacktrace.com/artifacts/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4/4.1/org.apache.commons.collections4.ListValuedMap), the class `org.apache.commons.collections4.ListValuedMap` is available in the version `4.1` of `org.apache.commons commons-collections4`lib.

**So I suggest you to upgrade your `org.apache.commons commons-collections4`lib to version `4.1`.**

Link : [commons-collections4-4.1.jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-collections4/4.1/commons-collections4-4.1.jar)

**Advice** : I recommand to use [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/index.html) or [Gradle](https://gradle.org/) to manage your Java project dependencies.

Comment: I have download this latest jar and added to my build path , but still getting the same error@ Mickael B

Comment: thanks Mickael ,4-4.1 has this file and that has saved my day.